3D trigonometry bearing question - finding the bearing of a point to a tower
I'm currently struggling with 3D trigonometry, particularly with drawing a proper diagram and interpreting bearings. The question is below:
The angle of elevation of a tower QR of height 100m at a point Y due east of it is 25 degrees. From another point X, the angle of elevation is 20 degrees. The distance between X and Y is 420m. The points X, Y and R are on the same level ground. Find the bearing of the tower from X.
I have a few questions about this:

Where should I draw the point X in relation to the tower?
Are there multiple ways to draw the diagram because the direction of point X is not specified? If so, does this change the answer of the problem (i.e. the bearing of the tower from X)
What does the bearing of the tower from X look like?

Thank you
Edit: I’ve put how I’ve interpreted the questions below in two diagrams. It seems in the first diagram the bearing will be between 90-180 degrees, while in the second it would be between 270-360 degrees. 

From the distance $RY$ and the first angle of elevation, find the height $QR$. From the height $QR$ and the second angle of elevation, find the distance $RX$. Then find $\angle XRY$ from the three distances.

The distances from $X$ and $Y$ to the tower can be determined from the data, so the triangle is determined up to isometry and there are really only two possible relative positions of $X,$ $Y$ and $T.$ You can get away with an answer between $0$ and $180$ degrees. At worst you will get the right absolute value of the expected answer.

There are two different questions embedded in this one question.
The first question: What are the distances of points X and Y from the tower?
To find this you will need to use the angle of elevation data.  The first figure below should help you get started.
The second question is once you have the distances, you must find point X spatially relative to Y.  That is what the second figure shows.  Note, that there will be two possible locations for X.  One where X is somewhat North of Y and one where X the same degree South of Y.
Once you find data for this triangle, you can calculate a bearing.


From your diagram (top one) can you see that you can figure out the distance of X and Y from the tower ($d_x$ and $d_y$) by using $tan(\theta_i) = 100/d_i$ with the different elevation angles, $\theta_x$ and $\theta_y$? Once you do, then have a SSS triangle defined on the ground. The angle between X and Y, $\phi$, can be found via the law of cosines: $420^2 = dx^2 + dy^2 -2d_x d_y \cos(\phi)$. But you could measure that angle in the positive or negative direction from the line connecting the T and Y. So yes, you will have two triangle possibilities.
